# How to change DS.Model url in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new(to ember) and trying to build a search centric Ember App w/ Ember-data also. I wanted to change the url on the fly(based on search string) and the data should change automatically(on the fly). How to do it?

This is my not working code:

```
Emapp.Data = DS.Model.extend({
first_name: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({
  url: Emapp.MyURL.get('url')
});

Emapp.MyURL = Em.Object.create({
  urlParam: 'John',
  url: function()
  {
    return 'emb/data.php?id=%@'.fmt(this.get('urlParam'));
  }.property('urlParam')
});
```

When I execute. emapp.MyURL.set('urlParam', 'Adams'). I can inspect and see the url changed to 'Adams'. But data is not fetched again.

Edit: emapp -> Emapp (pointed out by rudi-angela)

Answer (score 1):

As you have made the 'url' property a computed property, Ember takes care of updating this value when the urlParam changes. That is all you have instructed Ember to do here (and apparently it is doing it properly).
But I reckon what you want here is any change in the 'urlParam' property to trigger a fetch action. In that case a solution would be to create a separate object that observes the urlParam and will take action when the 'urlParam' value changes. Something along these lines:

```
emapp.watcher = Ember.Object.create({
    valueBinding: "emapp.MyURL.urlParam",

    observer: function() {
        console.log("urlParam has changed:");
        // perform your fetch here
    }.observes("value"),
});
```

Note: I thought there was a requirement for the namespace to be capitalised (rather Emapp instead of emapp).

Comment: I am able to observe the change. Now when I try to reload the data(no idea how to do it). `index: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
        connectOutlets:  function(router, context){
          router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home', router.get('store').findAll(Emapp.Data));
        }
    })` similarly I implemented `Emapp.watcher = Em.Object.create({
  valueBinding: "Emapp.MyURL.urlParam",
  observer: function(){
    console.log("urlParam has changed");
    BugUser.get('router').homeController.store.findAll(BugUser.Data);
  }.observes("value")
})`. nothing is happens.

Comment: Is there a less complicated way of do it?